Linkedin post date extractor as a bookmarketlet alert
I'd like to make a javascript bookmarklet for Chrome which generates the date of a linkedin.com post and creates an alert.
So the date of a post like this one from Bill Gates:
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/williamhgates_what-do-kangaroos-have-to-do-with-newborn-activity-7222643141433028611-LDNX/
I've used this website to find out it was posted on Fri, 26 Jul 2024
https://ollie-boyd.github.io/Linkedin-post-timestamp-extractor/
Is it possible to make the javascript that sits behind this webpage into a bookmarklet?
https://ollie-boyd.github.io/Linkedin-post-timestamp-extractor/extractor.js

I've tried editing:
const linkedinURL= document.querySelector("#url").value;

to change #url to
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname

And i tried changing the output to an alert()
I tried using javascript compression website to make it into a bookmarklet format

you don't need to use .value, that's just for getting the URL from the form field. Just use const linkedinURL = window.location.href. Everything else should be the same.

You don't actually need the whole URL. Just use window.location.pathanme. It's just looking for the long number in the pathname, which is the date as a numeric timestamp.
